# Scanner.hasNext based on beginning of next String

Tags: java

I am looking at the Scanner documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and I see that there are conditional hasNext methods that only return true if the next element satisfies a certain condition. Let's say I have the following scanner. How could I check whether the scanner's next term starts with an "a"?

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("asd ab anob");
```

Comment: Take the next string. Use startsWith method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern that it's talking about is a regular expression.

The regular expression for "starts with an a" is "^a.*"

```
boolean a = s.hasNext("^a.*");
```

Comment: What is the difference between s.hasNext("^a.*") and s.hasNext("a.*")?

Comment: There's probably no difference in this case.  ^ means "start of string", but since you are matching against the entire String in this case, it shouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The [hasNext(Pattern pattern)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext(java.util.regex.Pattern)) should do the job, or [hasNext(String pattern)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext(java.lang.String)) which additionally compiles the pattern from String to Pattern:

```
if (s.hasNext("^a.*"))
    ... // next token starts with "a"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("asd ab anob");

s.hasNext("a[a-z]*");
```

That matches "words" that consist of an 'a' followed by zero or more lower case "latin" letters.  The regular expression can be modified to give you different criteria for matching a "word".

If you are going to do this repeatedly, then the following is better:

```
private static Pattern WORD = Pattern.compile("a[a-z]*");

...

Scanner s = new Scanner("asd ab anob");
s.hasNext(WORD);
```

According to the javadoc, the normal rules for dealing with delimiters apply and the pattern matching is done using "match" semantics.  That implies that it is not necessary to use an "anchor" (e.g. "^") in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("asd ab anob");
String nextString = s.nextLine();
boolean result = nextString.startsWith("a");
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP is asking for.  He says he wants to make `hasNext(...)` match a token that starts with an 'a'.

Comment: Yep. Just miss understood it. Thanks.